# Pyaudio type error on OSX

Tags: python, audio, microphone, portaudio, pyaudio

I'm getting a type error when trying to do a basic microphone recording with pyaudio on OSX. I've freshly installed portaudio with brew, and install the most recent pyaudio with pip. They seem to install just fine. However when running my code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "micTest.py", line 37, in <module>
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

The code in question is :

```
import audioop
import pyaudio
import wave

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "file.wav"

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
print(audio.get_default_input_device_info())

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE, input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print "recording..."
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):

    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    mx = audioop.max(data, 2)
    print mx
    frames.append(data)


print "finished recording"


# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()

waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
waveFile.close()
```

The default_audio_device_info looks like:

```
{
 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0,
 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.01,
 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.00199546485260771,
 'maxInputChannels': 2L,
 'structVersion': 2L,
 'hostApi': 0L,
 'index': 0L,
 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.1,
 'maxOutputChannels': 0L,
 'name': u'Built-in Microph',
 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.012154195011337868
}
```

No idea what could be going wrong here or why the 'self' in the read method is being counted as an argument.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what's going wrong with PyAudio, but probably you might want to try the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/) module?

```
import sounddevice as sd
fs = 44100
myrec = sd.rec(RECORD_SECONDS * fs, fs, channels=2)
```

To store `myrec` as a file, you can use the [soundfile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.org/) module.